# Setting conditions within functions to continue

Tags: python, conditional-statements

How do I create a function to test if variables satisfy an given set of conditions to continue, else stops. If the variables satisfy the first set of conditions, it moves onto next set or else stops. This continues until all conditions are met to return a final answer.

```
> #the following are variables that can be changed if wanted
> lst = [5,4.3,8,2,9,3]
> len = 2
> interval = [-2.6,3.1]
> threshold = 1
> min = 1
```

First set of conditions are:

1. `len` must be a positive integer greater than or equal to 1
2. For `interval`, `interval[0]` must be strictly less than `interval[1]`
3. `threshold` must be a float strictly between 0 and 1, i.e. 0 and 1 not included
4. `min` must be a positive integer greater than or equal to 1

If all 4 conditions are satisfied, then function continues on else return the string 'Invalid'.

Second condition:
`lst` must contain at least 2 or more elements

If second condition is also satisfied, then function continues to return final answer, else returns the string `Not enough data'.

This is the function I have written so far, but is clearly incorrect:

```
> def conditions(lst,len,interval,threshold,min):
    if len >= 1 and interval[0] < interval[1] and 0 < threshold < 1 and min >= 1:
        continue 
    else:
        return str('Invalid')
    
    if lst >= 2
        continue 
    else:
        return str('Not enough data')
    
    return answer
```

Comment: It's not good practice to call variables `len` or `min`, since those are built-in functions, which you are overwriting with number values.

Answer (score 0):

This is not what `continue` is meant for. Just design your `if-else` block in a way that the program will follow a different path based on wether conditions are met or not.

Also try to use variable names that don't shadow built-in ones, to avoid undesired behaviour in your code:

```
def conditions(lst, length ,interval, threshold, minimum):
    if length >= 1 and interval[0] < interval[1] and threshold in range(0, 1) and minimum >= 1:
        if len(lst) < 2:
            answer = 'Not enough data'
        answer = "ok"
    else:
        answer = 'Invalid'
    return answer
```

Comment: If I ran this code and the first set of conditions isn't met (i.e. `length =-2`, will the function return `answer = 'Invalid'` and stop there, instead of continuing on to test if `len(lst) < 2`?